# How to connect a Webapplication to a Java-/ABAP-Application

Tags: java, abap, jco

I have a problem. I would like to connect my web application (frontend) with my application.

Once the web application is to be written in UI5 (frontend) and connected to an ABAP application (backend). The frontend is used for the control and the logic is in the backend. Which interface can be used for communication?

On the other hand, the web application should be written in Java (frontend) and connected to a Java application (backend). Here, too, the front-end of the controller is used and in the backend is the program logic. Which interface is needed here? XML?

Presentation: Web application Java (frontend) - Which SST? - Java program (backend) Web application UI5 (frontend) - Which SST? - ABAP program (backend)

I would really appreciate replies!

Comment: I think your question is a bit open-ended... For the Java-to-Java scenario, the simplest answer these days is probably to make the back end a RESTful service, and invoke it from the front end via REST calls over HTTP...

Comment: What means SST?

Comment: If the answer from Suncatcher was helpful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark to let others know that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Use SAP Jco connector for that. It allows exactly what you want.

[SAP Java Connector - SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi71/7.1/en-US/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Samples:

[Example Program JCo Client](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi711/7.1.1/en-US/48/634503d4e9501ae10000000a42189b/content.htm?no_cache=true)

[SAP JCo Server Example - SAP Blogs](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/25/sap-jco-server-example/)